# A More Elegant way to change the value of my div?

Tags: javascript, html, keystroke

Ok so, what I need to do is change some numbers on the screen when keys are pressed, i have it working but I'm not happy with it.

I have a input field and a div that is being updated when the value of the input filed changes. I did that so that I would not be constrained by the input field's blinking carat etc. I don't want to display the input field at all but when I hide it with CSS or type="hidden" it no longer works. I was trying to get this working with JS variables but so far have been unsuccessful.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="number.css" />
</head>

<body onLoad="focus();myText.focus();changeNumber()">

<div id='number'>

</div>

<input type="text" id="myText" value="1"/>

</body>

<footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="number.js"></script>
</footer>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var myText = document.getElementById("myText");

function changeNumber(){
var userInput = document.getElementById('myText').value;
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = userInput;
}

// Capture keyDown events
myText.onkeydown = function(e) {
// "34" is the up arrow key
if (e.keyCode == 34) {
    // increment the value in the text input
    myText.value++;
changeNumber()

// "33" is the down arrow key
} else if (e.keyCode == 33 && myText.value > 1) {
    // decrement the value in the text input
    myText.value--;
changeNumber()
}
}
```

HERE IN THE FINAL FIXED CODE *** THANKS GUYS! ****

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="number.css" />
</head>

<body onLoad="focus();number.focus();changeNumber()">

<div id='number' value="1">

</div>

</body>

<footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="number.js"></script>
</footer>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var i = parseInt(1);

function changeNumber(){
var userInput = i;
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = userInput;
}

// Capture keyDown events for document
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
// "34" is the PGUp key
if (e.keyCode == 34) {
    // increment the value in the text input
    (i++);
changeNumber()

// "33" is the PGDown key
} else if (e.keyCode == 33 && i > 1) {
    // decrement the value in the text input
    (i--);
changeNumber()
}

// "66" is the b key
if (e.keyCode == 66){
window.location.reload()
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is this:

```
myText.value--;
```

and

```
myText.value++;
```

`myText` is a DOM element, and the `value` property has a string, not an integer, I'd recommend doing:

```
var i = parseInt(myText.value);
myText.value = (i++);
```

Comment: I'll see what I can do with this, that makes sense, I'm not so great with javascript I usually program in objective c/iphone. :(